# How to animate the navigation link on press in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, user-experience, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to improve UX by giving some feedback when the NavigationLink() is pressed.
By this I mean a simple animation that grows then shrinks the link to show that it was pressed or any other way to provide feedback.

This is the code I'm trying to improve:

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: TrickView(trickId: begginerTricks[index]["trickId"] as! String),
    label: {
        TrickRowView(name: begginerTricks[index]["trickName"] as! String,
        trickType: begginerTricks[index]["trickType"] as! String,
        trickComplete: [false,false,false,false],
        width: width * 0.73, height: height * 0.13)
})
.padding(.bottom, 15)
```

This is one NavigationLink in a list of navigation links.

Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code of "trying to improve"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to add animation to your navigation link.
Here is one of them.
You can create `ButtonStyle` and apply it to the navigation link with the use of `scaleEffect`, `background`, or you can also add additional to as per your choice.

ButtonStyle :

```
struct ThemeAnimationStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.title2)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.green.opacity(0.5) : Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1.0) //<- change scale value as per need. scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: Text("Destination view"),
            label: {
                Text("MyButton")
                    .padding()
            })
            .buttonStyle(ThemeAnimationStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]