# Programmatic NavigationLink push in , there is no animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There is no any animation on programatic navigation link when it pushes in. Is there a way to animate it like the default style?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingDetailView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), isActive: $isShowingDetailView) { EmptyView() }

                Button("Tap to show detail") {
                    isShowingDetailView = true
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks all!

**SOLVED!!**

On my actual code, there was a if-else (see the code above). So because of that the animation of NavigationLink was not working. I removed it and it started to work.

```
if isShowingDetailView { //remove if else
  NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), isActive: $isShowingDetailView) { EmptyView() }
}
```

Comment: Opps, sorry guys I fixed the title. 
I want to animate it like the default style.

Comment: Looks like there is animation to me (iOS 15, iPhone 12). What device and OS version are you testing on?

Comment: Interesting... I use iOS 15 iPhone 11 and iOS 15 simulators

Comment: When I tap to button, the view immediately opens without scrolling animation.

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to add animation in swift UI . I have made one fully customisable `button style` to animate when click the link using `scaleEffect`.
You may use to get a simple animation on clicking the navigation link. you can modify as you need on this code.

Here is the code to struct the `Buttonstyle`:

```
struct AnimatedButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.title2) //change font style as well as 
            .foregroundColor(Color.white) // use your color
            .frame(height: 48, alignment: .center) // use height and width as you need 
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.green.opacity(0.5) : Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0) // for adding shadow
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1.0) // here is the scale vale you can modify to change animation scale 
    }
}
```

**Using on Navigation Link:**

```
VStack{
    NavigationLink(
            destination: Text("Details view"),
            label: {
                Text("Go Details")
                    .padding()
            })
            .buttonStyle(AnimatedButton())
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. It is so valuable. Please see my answer above for solution

Comment: So you basically reposted this answer, including all the same numbers, and without even mentioning the source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668755/how-to-animate-the-navigation-link-on-press-in-swiftui. Not nice!